# How to show that the order in which multiple sums are performed does not matter

Tags: matrices, summation

So let $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{nm} (R)$

I need to show that:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n$($\sum\limits_{j=1}^m a_{ij}$)=
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^m$($\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$)

(the order in which multiple sums are performed does not matter.)

Comment: Probably not sufficiently rigorous for your purposes, but the first of Knuth's [Two notes on notation](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211) is relevant.

Comment: Both of those are the sum of all the elements in the matrix. Addition is commutative and associative.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but is that the only proof I require?

Answer (score 1):

Double induction in $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Can you expand on that please?

Comment: Check that it is true for $n=m=1$ (it clearly is), then assume it is true for a given value of $m$ and keep fixed $n=1$. Use induction to prove that it will be valid for $m+1$ (and still $n=1$), so you have proved it for $n=1$ and any $m$. As a second step now make induction on $n$: assume that it is true for $(n,m)$ (you have already proved it is true for $(1,m)$) and use induction to prove it will be true for $(n+1,m)$, once you do this you have proved it for any finite $n,m \geq 1$.